# Show Error popup if current form is invalid and tried to go to another Route In angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a TAB structure like below :
[image]

Each tab have seperate form and I have used angular Routes to navigate to the tabs:

like :

```
onboardingApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/empDetails', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/employeeDetails.html',
            controller: 'empDetailsController',
            activeLink: 'empDetails',
            data: {
                login: false
            }
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController',
            activeLink: 'login',
            data: {
                login: true
            }
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/accType', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/accountType.html',
            controller: 'accountTypeController',
            activeLink: 'accType',
            data: {
                login: false
            }
        });

        $routeProvider.when('/verifyID', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/identityVerification.html',
            controller: 'verifyIdentityController',
            activeLink: 'verifyID',
            data: {
                login: false
            }
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/personalDetails', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/personalDetails.html',
            controller: 'personalDetailsController',
            activeLink: 'personalDetails',
            data: {
                login: false
            }
        });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('APIInterceptor');

    }]);
```

What I want to do is if form under Account Creation is not valid and user try to navigate to another any tab lets say Personal Details then, there should be Error Popup showing that Data is not filled in Account Creation.
I have markup for the popup ready and I have used $modal from Angular UI bootstrap.

Is there any way to do this in Route's Resolve property ?

IF user click Identity verification and form under Account Creation is invalid then also I need to show the Error popup.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="error.html">
    <form id="form1" name="form1">
    <div class="">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" ng-click="cancel()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="customOptions topMargin">
                    <span class="error"></span>
                    <p>You have not filled {{tabData}} Data</p>
                </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</form>
</script>
```

How to achieve this ?